# EXE from Delphi 2006 : Buttons/Checkbox/Radios not visible until mouse is hovered (on Vista/Win7)

Tags: delphi, windows-7, controls, windows-vista, invisible

Under Windows Vista and Win7 there is a problem with applications created by Delphi (we use Delphi 2006, but it seems other versions have the same problem) which contain the XP manifest.

All descendants of TButtonControl (TButton, TCheckBox, TRadioButton, but not TBitBtn) are not visible after a form is initially shown. The controls appear when you move the mouse over them. And it only happens once for each form, until I restart the application.

It seems to be related to the hiding/showing of the accelerator keys (defualt is hidden on Vista/Win7).

What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is the [best / easiest workaround](http://exodus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/exodus/VistaAltFixUnit.pas). It just requires one line of code in main form's OnCreate.

Comment: The VistaAltFix http://exodus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/exodus/VistaAltFixUnit.pas works perfectly, without any hassle. Thanks a lot.

Comment: VistaAltFix causes the application to crash from time to time, especially on termination. TFormObj.WndProc will still be called by the form it is supposed to fix after TFormObj has been destroyed.

Comment: In case if you are fixing this problem with TVistaAltFix be careful. From time to time I get errors while closing the form in this unit: `unit VistaAltFixUnit; procedure TFormObj.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);` One of my software users reports constant crashes on exit.

Answer (score 9):

[This is a Delphi bug](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=37403).

Answer (score 3):

The problem disappears if you compile a new XP manifest and replace WindowsXP.res with it.

Answer (score 0):

procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
    if Key = 18 then Key := 0;
end;